What are the requirements for the "And They'll Tell Two Friends" achievement?
I'm trying to get the various achievements in Borderlands (1) — the original, not the remaster — and one in particular is causing me problems, "And They'll Tell Two Friends". The description of the achievement, "Gamed with fame", doesn't really say what one needs to do to get it. However, it seems like the general consensus online is that there are two possible ways of getting it:

Playing co-op with a Gearbox employee
Playing co-op with someone who has the achivement

I have a friend on my Steam friend list who has it, so I created a lobby and invited her. But, once she joined and we started the game, nothing happened. I looked through Steam community forum posts and found people suggesting various things, like that the person with the achievement has to be the host, that you need to specifically press "Join game" through Steam, or that you need to use new characters. We tried all of these, but nothing worked. To be clear, we didn't play particularly long (a few minutes at most), but I never found anyone mentioning a time requirement.
Given that this didn't work, what are the requirements for getting this achievement in the original, non-remaster, Borderlands (1)? Are there are any additional requirements which I'm missing?

Apparently, the person who owns the achievement does not have to delete their saves as the trophy is not tied to the PSN id/gamertag. You should get this achivement very easy by just joining a public game, you don't have to ready up and go ingame, just the lobby will work fine

@pinckerman Sorry, what do you mean by that the person "does not have to delete their saves"?

I read that online, as I understand you have to play with someone who still has the savegame when the achievement was unlocked, it's not enough to play with someone who has obtained it in the past, apparently.

@pinckerman I asked and she only has one character apart from the new one she created for this, so it doesn't seem like that was the problem.

Have you tried the public game solution?

According to Steam community:
Play with someone who got it within the last 12 months, or play with an Gearbox Employee.

I got this one at random when I just started playing online shortly after the release.
The first result on the internet comes with the following answer:

original: play with an employee of gearbox or someone with this achievement
changed to: play with two friends

source: borderlands fandom

Yeah, but as written in the question just playing with someone having this achievement didn't work.

my apologies, I read the question to quickly, did the playing with 2 friends work?

No, since as noted in my question, I'm playing the original, not the remaster. I'm currently doing a playthrough of the whole game with two friends.
